# JavaScript Change focus to password field login page being reset

Tags: theme-development, javascript, wp-login-form

I have a special situation where I want users on the standard WordPress login page enter a password. I'm filling in the username with a line of javascript:

```
document.getElementById('user_login').value = 'username';
```

By default the focus starts on the username field. I want to have the focus start on the password field...

```
document.getElementById('user_pass').focus();
```

but this isn't working. It looks like it might be focusing on the password field for a moment and then going back to the username field.

Any idea why this might be happening and how to fix it?

(I don't want to just hide the username field, I need actual admins to be able to login as usual. This special autofilled username only gets role access to one little part of the site. And I don't want to use a password protected page for other reasons.)

Comment: maybe its the timing of the JS?  As a test you could put your code inside a setTimeout() or inside of $(window).load().

Comment: I did try it in a docment.ready... i'll try those.

Comment: That seems to have done it. I don't really know what the difference between $(document).ready() and $(window).load() is but there you go. The set timeout also worked, but seems less reliable.

Comment: Glad it worked,  I went ahead and moved my comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a timing issue, there is probably already some JS running after your script is ran.

Try wrapping your JS in $(window).load(), this will run the function after other page assets have loaded and should fix the timing issue.

For example...

```
$(window).load(function() {
    document.getElementById('user_pass').focus();
});
```

[Here is some info](https://coderwall.com/p/_jothq/jquery-when-to-use-document-ready-and-when-window-load) about the difference between $(document).ready() vs $(window).load().